# Django Checkout in an ecommerce application

Tags: django

I have an ecommerce application which was written based on tutorials found in a book. after implementing everything, I decided to improve it because according to the book, customers have to imput their details everytime they want to checkout from the application and this is very unprofessional. I have included all my codes in my GitHub because I cant include every bit of the code. https://github.com/Olar19/ecommerce . I have worked on this trying to improve it for some months and I just cannot wrap my head around it. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty broad ask.  Open ended with help improving - could be UI/ UX, flow, design, security.  I wish I could help but this will take some time.  I'd recommend going on Upwork and finding someone who has implemented one before and offer to buy their time.  Otherwise, I'd try to refine you ask a little bit more.  Can somebody who know ecommerce system architecture spend 30 minutes on skype with me on how I could improve this.  Ecomm is scary to roll yourself because it can be difficult to really test and the stakes are so high.  Hope this helps.  I've been in your shoes many times.

Comment: I could Skype if you can. Or FaceTime.